# Upload file to MinIO server from URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, minio

I have an image's URL. Can I upload it directly to MinIO without saving them to a server?

Comment: Which interface are you referring to? The web frontend? JS? Python? `mc`? Please reformat your question to include this information, along with what you'd tried to do.

Comment: I'm using NodeJs